# How to concatenate 3 separate UDP packets?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, concatenation

This question has probably been asked before but I can't seem to find it.
I am trying to send 3 individual packets between a client and a server. That part I can do, however I need to take those 3 packets and add them together and print the result.

That's the part I am having trouble with. I have never programmed before and have only really started so I am new to all this and please be gentle with what is probably awful coding on my part!

This is what I have for the client:

```
import socket

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 

UDP_IP = "localhost" 
UDP_PORT = 6842 
address = ("localhost" , 6842)

s1 = str(input("Please enter Packet number 1: "))
clientSock.sendto(bytes("s1", "utf-8"), (address))
s2 = str(input("Please enter Packet number 2: "))
clientSock.sendto(bytes("s2", "utf-8"), (address)) 
s3 = str(input("please enter Packet number 3: ")) 
clientSock.sendto(bytes("s3", "utf-8"), (address))

print ("Sent 3 packets to server")
print ("Waiting to receive message...")
```

And this is what I have for the server:

```
import socket

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 6842
address = ("localhost" , 6842)

serverSocket.bind(address) 
print ("Waiting for client...")

while True:
    data,addr = serverSocket.recvfrom(6842)
    print ("Received:",data," from",addr) 
    n = len('s1' , 's2' , 's3')
    R = "s1" + "#" + "s2" + "#" + "s3"
    print (n)
    print (R)
```

Again there are probably quite a few flaws in this but was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: To do this you will need to create a new UDP packet that contains the combined contents of the 3 you have. From the Wikipedia article on the [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) it looks like doing so would be fairly complicated — so I suggest you learn Python better first before trying to program this.

Comment: Well I am currently doing a degree in computing that started in October of last year which is when I was first introduced to Python and this piece is for a bit of coursework I am doing so I need to learn fast haha. It states I have to send 3 distinct UDP packets and then get the server to concatenate them so I thought they had to be individually sent packets instead of combined.

Comment: Even if you had a degree in Computer Science, to program this in Python, I think you're going to need to know the language much better. One can often avoid the messy details of data formats by using an existing library/module. There are a built-in one named [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver) that might prove helpful — but I'm not sure because I'm no UDP expert.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help. I will study Python as much as I can!

Answer (score 0):

I think your server just wants to do something closer to:

```
while True:
  values = []
  for i in range(3):
    values.append(float(sock.recv(1024)))
  print(sum(values))
```

note that UDP is unreliable, so you might not always receive the three packets sent from the client

you can also compress the contents of the `while` loop into a single line, and hence avoid creating any list, but I'll leave that up to you!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Sam I will give that a go!